# Measuring the speed difference between a statically bound call and a dynamically bound call?

Tags: c++, dynamic, time, static

I am trying to measure the speed difference between a statically bound call and a dynamically bound call but the time are all over the place. Sometimes the static call is faster and sometimes the dynamically bound call is faster. Am i doing this wrong? I was under the impression hat static calls are faster then dynamically bound calls.

Main

```
#include "Parent.h"
#include "Child.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int choice = 1;
    do
    {
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            Parent P;
            clock_t begin_time = clock(); 
            P.calc();
            cout << "Time for statically bound call, " << float(clock() -     begin_time) << " miliseconds.";

            Child C;
            clock_t begin_time2 = clock();
            C.calc();
            cout << endl << "Time for dynamically bound call, " << float(clock() - begin_time2) << " miliseconds." << endl << endl;
         }
         cout << "1 to go again, 2 to stop. ";
         cin >> choice;
         cout << endl;
      }while(choice != 2);

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Parent implementation

```
#ifndef PARENT_H
#define PARENT_H

class Parent
{
public:

    Parent();
    virtual void calc();

protected:
    int size;
};
#endif

Parent::Parent()
{
    size = 100000;
}

void Parent::calc()
{
    vector<int> myvector;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        myvector.push_back(i);
    }
 }
```

Child implementation

```
#ifndef CHILD_H
#define CHILD_H
#include "Parent.h"

class Child: public Parent
{
public:

    Child();
    void calc();
};
#endif

Child::Child()
    :Parent()
{
}

void Child::calc()
{
    Parent::calc();
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you are even comparing a statically bound call to a dynamically bound call?  I don't think you are.  But if you were, there is so much other execution time there that any difference would be completely obscured.

Comment: The time difference is much, much smaller than the time a *single* memory allocation takes, let alone all those push_backs.

Comment: @JSF by having the child class calc function virtually call the parent class calc function doesnt that make it a dynamic call?

Comment: So much wrong with this code. 1) `P.calc()` will also go through the virtual table, so you're measuring the same thing. Call `P.Parent::calc()`. 2) I'm pretty sure the optimizer will devirtualize all of this 3) You're mostly measuring `push_back` 4) you're trying to measure the difference on a level of nanoseconds with `clock()` whose granularity is insane (try `std::chrono::steady_clock`) 5) You're not measuring many runs and averaging - too much potential influence from the rest of the system. Overall, rethink your test.

Comment: Oh wait, there's no need for devirtualization. You're not even using pointers to base class - the compiler will directly call the correct function.